# ListActivity does not update when inheriting BaseListActivity and using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listactivity

I have a class SomeActivity extends BaseListActivity. The BaseListActivity extends ListActivity and all that works.

But when the list has to update, I use a remote server call using AsyncTask which is declared like this:

```
public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

In there, there is a line to update the list like this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but this line does not seem to do anything.

Any idea what should be different to make it work?

Here is the BaseListActivity

```
public class BaseListActivity extends ListActivity {

    public ListView getListView() {
        return (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }

    public ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
        return getListView().getAdapter();
    }   

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {    
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        {
            setListAdapter(this.getListAdapter());

            Button home_header = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_header);
            Button questions_header = (Button) findViewById(R.id.questions_header);

            home_header.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(BaseListActivity.this,
                            ProblemioActivity.class);
                    BaseListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });

            questions_header.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(BaseListActivity.this,
                            MyQuestionsActivity.class);
                    BaseListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the entire DownloadWebPageTask code:

public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask 
{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
        {
            String myUrl = theParams[0];
            final String user_id = theParams[1];

```
        String charset = "UTF-8";           
        String response = null;

        try 
        {                           
            String query = String.format("user_id=%s", 
                     URLEncoder.encode( user_id, charset) );

            final URL url = new URL( myUrl + "?" + query );

            Log.d( "QuestionUserURL" , url+ "" );

            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.connect();

            final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

            response = builder.toString();      
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                Log.d( "EXCEPTIONNNN: " , "Yup" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d( "MyQuestionsActivity" , "*** Response: " + response );
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        Log.d( "MyQuestionsActivity" , "In the post-execute method: " + result );

        if ( result != null && result.trim().equals( "no_user_id" ) )
        {
            Log.d( "Post execute: " , "NOOOT  OKKKK - no user id" );    
            // Show the user a message that they did not enter the right login

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not get your questions. We are working to fix this. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                

        sendEmail("Error in My Questions", "The questions by user did not load because on the server the validation for user id said the user id was empty." );     
        }
        else
        if ( result != null && result.trim().equals( "database_error" ) )
        {
            Log.d( "Post execute: " , "NOOOT  OKKKK - no user database error" );    
            // Show the user a message that they did not enter the right login

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not get your questions. We are working to fix this. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                

        sendEmail("Error in My Questions", "The questions by user did not load because on the server there " +
                "was a database error." );                  
        }
        else
        if ( result != null && result.trim().equals( "no_questions_by_user" ) )
        {           
            // Show the user a message that they did not enter the right login

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have not asked any questions.  Ask your business questions! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                

        //sendEmail("No Questions so far in My Questions", "User got message that they do not have questions." );           

        TextView question_label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_label);
        question_label.setText("You have not asked any business questions.  Ask your question." );
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d( "MyQuestionsActivity" , "In JSON parsing area.." );

                try
                {   
                    JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

                    if ( obj != null )
                    {
                        questions.clear();

                        for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                        {
                            JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                            String question_id = o.getString("question_id");
                            String question = o.getString("question");
                            String questioner_id = o.getString("member_id");
                            String first_name = o.getString("first_name");
                            String last_name = o.getString("last_name");

                            Log.d( "Question: " , question );                               
                            Log.d( "Question_id: " , question_id );       

                            Question q = new Question ( );
                            q.setQuestion(question);
                            q.setQuestionId(question_id);
                            q.setQuestionByMemberId( questioner_id );

                            q.setAuthorName(first_name + " " + last_name );

                            questions.add( q );
                        }
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    TextView question_label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_label);
                    question_label.setText("The questions you asked are below. Choose one or ask a new question.");
                }                   
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    Log.d( "MyQuestionsActivity: " , "some crap happened 1: " + e.getMessage() );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                       
        }
    }
```

and this is the exception I now see in the logs:

```
05-26 19:59:55.774: W/System.err(3103): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.problemio.com": No address associated with hostname
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:426)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
05-26 19:59:55.777: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
05-26 19:59:55.797: W/System.err(3103):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
05-26 19:59:55.807: W/System.err(3103):     at utils.SendEmail.doInBackground(SendEmail.java:38)
05-26 19:59:55.807: W/System.err(3103):     at utils.SendEmail.doInBackground(SendEmail.java:1)
05-26 19:59:55.819: W/System.err(3103):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-26 19:59:55.827: W/System.err(3103):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-26 19:59:55.827: W/System.err(3103):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-26 19:59:55.837: W/System.err(3103):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-26 19:59:55.837: W/System.err(3103):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-26 19:59:55.847: W/System.err(3103):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-26 19:59:55.847: W/System.err(3103):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-26 19:59:55.956: W/System.err(3103): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
05-26 19:59:56.177: D/dalvikvm(3103): GC_CONCURRENT freed 406K, 6% free 9330K/9863K, paused 32ms+6ms
```

BUT the exception is not accurate.  I am able to resolve that host no problem.  And before I added the BaseListActivity this same code used to work.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using? can you show the `DownloadWebPageTask` code?

Comment: @Chopin thanks, just added the code and the exception, and notes below those.

Comment: Did u gave the permission of Internet access in Android Manifest.xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reasigning the `ListAdapter` to the `ListView` will do the same as calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, i think `notifyDataSetChanged();` only works when you are using database `Cursor` object as data provider. instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` just call `setListAdapter();` which intern will rebuild the `ListView`.

Comment: You are wrong, adapters notifyDataSetChanged() method is appriopriate regardless what kind of data structure the adapter is based on. if it were for cursor data only it would then be declared in CursorAdapter, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: The method `notifyDataSetChanged` comes from the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, and `SimpleCursorAdapter` comes from `BaseAdapter`. But `ListAdapter` comes from `Adapter` not `Base Adapter`. OS i don't think I am wrong.

Comment: yea...but `ListAdapter` doesn't

Comment: ListAdapter nor SpinneAdapter Interfaces does not. But it is BaseAdapter abstract class from which most adapters inherit. so if adapter has notifyDataSetChanged, then it surely to be used ;)